# How to maintain a sorted data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, insert

I have a list of 300 files (data frames) each of nearly 80000 rows and 4 columns. I annotate all the 300 files and generate a single annotated data frame suppose df2 . I want to maintain my generated data frame in a sorted order without sorting it each time when a row is increased, as sorting it each time takes ages. My final data frame should look like this, which is in a sorted order.

```
Gene Name                                         file1         file2       file3
actin, beta                                        NA             P          NA
chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5                     P              P           P
cytochrome P450, family 2, subfamily               A              NA          P 
cytochrome P450, family 2, subfamily E,   1P       NA             A           P
discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1        P              NA          P
EPH receptor B3                                    P              P           P
estrogen-related receptor alpha                    NA             P           NA
glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase           NA             P           NA
```

`Note:` Why i want to maintain a sorted data frame is because in between i need to do other search operation, so sequential search take a lot of time. By maintaining a sorted data frame, i can easily go for binary search which saves a lot of time.

I have written the following code, but it sorts the data each time when an entry is made in the data frame.

```
p=1
    if (i == 1) ## file 1    
    {
        df2[p,1]=df1[k,10]       ## writing into the data frame
        df2[p,2]= df[[i]][j,3]
        df2=d1[do.call(order, d1),]   
        print(d1)
        p+1
    }
```

So i want to insert into a sorted data frame without sorting it again and again.

Edited: Suppose i have 300 files like this.

```
*ID_REF**       VALUE**  ABS_CALL**
AFFX-BioB-5_at  757.7    P
AFFX-BioB-M_at  933.7    P
AFFX-BioB-3_at  525.6    P
AFFX-BioC-5_at  1999.5   P
AFFX-BioC-3_at  2339.5   P
AFFX-BioDn-5_at 4321.3   P
AFFX-BioDn-3_at 9229.4   P
```

I have GPL (master) file like below:

```
*ID_REF**              Gene Name
AFFX-BioB-5_at         discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1    
AFFX-BioB-M_at         EPH receptor B3                                  
AFFX-BioB-3_at         estrogen-related receptor alpha               
AFFX-BioC-5_at         glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase 
AFFX-BioC-3_at         actin, beta                                       
AFFX-BioDn-5_at        chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5                     
AFFX-BioDn-3_at        cytochrome P450, family 2, subfamily
```

Now i am reading first id of `file1` `(AFFX-BioB-5_at)` to get its gene name from master file which is `( discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1)` and its detection call from file1 which is `p`to put in a new data frame , let it be df2. The same process will be done for other `IDs` also.

`df2`

```
Gene Name                                         file1
discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1        P
EPH receptor B3                                    P
estrogen-related receptor alpha                    NA
 actin, beta                                       NA    `### new gene not in order`
```

As you can see above the gene names are not in sorted order after `actin,beta` adds. so put the gene before `discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1`. So modified df2 will be

```
Gene Name                                         file1
actin, beta                                        NA
discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1        P
EPH receptor B3                                    P
estrogen-related receptor alpha                    NA
```

`Note` This problem is not as sorting the data at once after all the data is generated.
 I hope now it is clear.

Comment: I may have missed the point, but when you insert a value in a sorted data.frame column, doesn't the value needs to be sorted in the dataset.

Comment: @ akrun, not all the values(rows), it should put the new value in its location. i am not sure, but i think it should behave more likely as a linked list where we can insert at a particular location.

Comment: Suppose if a value `8` is the new entry in a vector `v1 <- c(2,4,7,9,11)`, it needs to be placed in the 4th position and the elements below it had to go down one position..

Comment: suppose my data frame generation goes one by one in a row manner, each time i have to sort the data, that takes much time. to avoid that sorting again and again, it should maintain a sorted data frame and put the new row in its order.

Comment: yeah u r right. i want to make a room for that new element

Comment: @ arun. my file1 matches some value from a master file and fetch that value in a new data frame corresponding to its file1 value. this need to be done till all the 300 files exhaust. so the generation of my data frame goes 1 by 1. Binary search is done to check the value if it is already in the data frame, than increment to a column will go corresponding to the same value say file 2. if not found, then increment to both row and column will be done.

Comment: @ arun.. row number is not know. it will go on increasing when a new value is found which is not in the data frame.

Comment: `@arun`  , thank U.. i can put it in simple words how to insert in a sorted data frame  like inserting in a sorted list but not sorting the list on each iteration.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, this is getting us nowhere.

Comment: @RomanLastrik... Editing done